# Getting a Fatal Exception when I call a certain method that disables a button for a quarter second

Tags: android

I am making a music playing and I have `next` and `previous` buttons. I don't want the user to button mash these, so I am trying to but those buttons on a quarter second delay.

The code for my next button (previous button is same):

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View button) {
                try {
                    taskMaster(2);
                    String newPath = nextPath();
                    instanceSongPlayer isp = new instanceSongPlayer(newTitle(1), album, titles, titlePlace, thisInstance, context, newPath, _activity);
                    isp.taskMaster(1);
                    isp.countdown();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

`instanceSongPlayer` is the name of the class

`taskMaster(1)` preps the `MediaPlayer` and begins the song

The code for `countdown()` is:

```
static Timer bd;

private static void countdown(){
    next.setEnabled(false);
    previous.setEnabled(false);
    bd = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            next.setEnabled(true);
            previous.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    bd.schedule(task, 250);
}
```

(I made it static in the hopes that this would magically solve all of my problems)

This is the error that I am getting:

```
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-2
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743): Process: com.mdc.etuna, PID: 11743
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:857)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10878)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:14969)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:203)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.invalidateDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:286)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:344)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:575)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:345)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:106)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:491)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15120)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged(ImageView.java:999)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:15134)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:6067)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at com.mdc.etuna.instanceSongPlayer$1.run(instanceSongPlayer.java:101)
01-24 13:32:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11743):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Could anyone give me any ideas to remedy the situation? Since I am calling `countDown()` from the new instance of `instanceSongPlayer`, I don't know what could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TimerTask` is running in a thread that isn't the UI thread. You can't access UI elements from another thread.

In your task, use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to have your UI thread enable the button.

Comment: Thank you, this was an easy fix!